# Add padding to Storybook canvas if not full screen?

Tags: storybook

I need to add padding around the canvas in Storybook for the normal view, but not in the fullscreen view.

Ive managed to do this but it feels a bit hacky. I've created a `manager-head.html` file and targetd the iframe via CSS within in:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #storybook-preview-iframe {
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
</style>
```

Is there a cleaner way?